# Proof of isomorphism between $D_{2n}$ and $D_n \times Z_2$ for $n$ odd

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

If we define a function $\phi : D_{2n} \rightarrow D_n \times Z_2$ for odd $n$ and we want to show that it is an isomorphic function, I am not very sure how to do it. 
We know that $D_{2n} = \{e, r, \ldots, r^{2n-1}, s, rs,\ldots, r^{2n-1}s\}$ and $D_n = \{e, t, \ldots, t^{n-1}, u, tu, \ldots, t^{n-1}u\}$.

I think that if we define $\phi(r) = (t, 1)$, then we can show that it is a homomorphism by showing that $\phi(r)\phi(r) = (t, 1)(t, 1) = (t^2, 0) = \phi(r^2)$, but I do not know if this is enough already or if I have to do it for all possibilities?!

And then the bijection. I know that it is injective if $\phi(a) = \phi(b) \iff a = b$, but how do I prove it in this particular example? And how do I show that every element of $D_n \times Z_2$ has an element in $D_{2n}$ to prove surjectivity?

Comment: In the first line, did you mean that $n$ is even ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You will also need to define $\phi(s)$; since $D_{2n}$ is generated by $r$ and $s$, this will fully define $\phi$. It then suffices to show that the homomorphism property holds for $r^2$, $rs$, $sr$ (and $s^2=e$). For bijection, note that you need only show *either* injectivity or surjectivity since the two sets have the same size.

Comment: Thank you very much! I showed that the homomorphism holds for $r^2, rs, sr$ and $s^2$. I said that it has to be injective, because every element  $D_{2n}$ has a different outcome under $\phi(x)$ and the order is the same. Is this the correct way to prove the injection?

Comment: Almost. Just showing that every element of $D_2n$ maps to a distinct element in $D_n\times\Z/2$ is enough to show injectivity since that is the *definition* of being injective. The fact that the two sets have the same size and are finite implies that any injective map is surjective.