# Is $D_{2n}$ isomorphic to $D_n \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ for all $n$? For all odd $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

> Is $D_{2n}$ isomorphic to $D_n \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ for all $n$? For all odd $n$?

I just want to see if my thinking is sound here. My thought process is this.

$\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \{e,j\} \subset D_n$

where $e$ is the identity and $j$ is a reflection about some axis.

let $\phi \colon D_n \times \{e,j\} \to D_{2n}$ defined by the map

$(a,b) \mapsto ab$

This is a surjective homomorphism and because the sizes are the same, it is an isomorphism.

Is this right? Have I done enough?

Comment: I take it you are using $D_n$ for the symmetries of a regular $n$-gon. $D_4$ is certainly not isomorphic to $D_2\times{\bf Z}_2$, as one is abelian, not the other.

Comment: It is only for when n is odd.

Comment: Could you say more about why your mapping is a homomorphism? (Keep in mind that $a \in D_{n}$ and $b \in \{e, j\}$, and that $a$ and $b$ probably have customary (and different) interpretations as elements of $D_{2n}$.)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961494/proof-of-isomorphism-between-d-2n-and-d-n-times-z-2-for-n-odd?rq=1). See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322685/let-n-geq-1-be-an-odd-integer-show-that-d-2n-cong-mathbbz-2-times-d-n).