# Prove that $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z/2Z}$ is isomorphic to $D_6$. Can you make a conjecture about $D_{2n}$? Prove that conjecture.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I already have shown that product $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z/2Z}$ is isomorphic to $S_6$, by taking the subgroups $H = \{id, r^3\}$ and $K = \{id, r^2,r^4,s,sr^2,sr^4\}$ and multiplying $KH$ to get the group $D_6$. I do not know what I can conjecture in general about $D_{2n}$ (or consequently how to prove that).

Comment: Remember that $S_3 = D_3$

Comment: It isn't a direct product, but it can be isomorphic to one (though I am still not convinced by his proof)

Comment: The result you're looking for is an isomorphism $D_{2n} = D_n \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, with certain restrictons on $n$ that I'll let you work out for yourself. To get an idea of what the isomorphism should look like, start by considering the centers of the two groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n$ is *odd*, then we have $D_{2n}\simeq D_n\times C_2$. This has been asked before at MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529983/is-d-2n-isomorphic-to-d-n-times-bbbz-2-for-all-n-for-all-odd-n). We have
$$
D_{2 n} = \langle a, b : a^{2n} = 1, b^{2} = 1, b a b = a^{-1} \rangle.
$$
Note that $a^{n}$ has order $2$, and it is central, as it commutes with $a$, and also with $b$, as $b a^{n} b = a^{-n} = a^{n}$. Now we have that
$
\langle a^{2}, b \rangle
$
is a subgroup of index $2$, isomorphic to $D_{n}$, which intersects $\langle a^{n} \rangle$ trivially. 
For $n$ even it is not true. Already $D_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_2\times C_2$, as $D_4$ is not abelian, but $D_2\times C_2$ is.

Comment: To explicitly rule out the decomposition in the case of $n$ even you can observe that $Z(D_{2n})\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, while $Z(D_n\times C_2)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.